# How to retrieve emails from iCloud account that is full

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, email

I recently received an email from Apple letting me know that because my iCloud storage was full I could not back up my devices and would not be able to send or receive mail. I did the usual deleting of unnecessary backups of emails, apps, and devices. I also purchased more storage.

This morning, I received my receipt for the new storage and a bunch of emails sent today. But I need the emails from yesterday and whenever they decided to shut down the account. How do I retrieve all the emails that I hope are in limbo somewhere?  Note: I sent an email from another account to see if I'd get an "undeliverable" message and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too. I spoke with Apple support on the phone and because my email was an iCloud email, they said there is most likely no way I would receive the emails I missed while my storage was full. The people sending the emails most likely received a bounce message indicating the mail was not delivered.